# javascript how to write a function that handles dynamic method chaining

Tags: javascript, method-chaining, supertest

So lets say I have the following method

```
api.post('users')
        .set(key,value);
        .send(data)
        .expect(201)
```

I was curious in javascript how I could set up a function to dynamically call/chain .set on the first method based on the number of keys in an object? So if I had the object `foo = {a: 1, b:2 , c:2}`

the function would behave like the following

```
 api.post('users')
            .set(a,1)
            .set(b,2)
            .set(c,3)
            .send(data)
            .expect(201)
```

Comment: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/4676-chaining-fluent-interfaces-in-javascript.html

Comment: Why don't you change your `.set()` method so it allows you to set multiple variables, e.g. `.set({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})`?

Comment: Chaining is accomplished by simply returning `this` or some object that contains the next method from each method, but if your  methods are async and you want the next one to only be called after the previous one has completed, it is much more complicated than that.

Answer (score 3):

The function can simply call `.set` in a loop:

```
function setMultiple(api, values) {
    for (var key in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            api = api.set(key, values[key]));
        }
    }
    return api;
}
```

Comment: …and then make this a method of `api`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = {a: 1, b:2, c:2 }
var apiPost = api.post("users");
for(var key in foo){
     apiPost = apiPost.set(key,foo[key]);
}

apiPost.send(data).expect(201);
```

Comment: Remember this only works if the order of your set calls is not important :)